# How to push array to JSON object in angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have an obj like below

```
let obj = {staff_changes: []};
```

Here are some test cases:

1. test case -->  success

   ```
   for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    obj.staff_changes.push({
     id: 'staff'+i
    });
   }
   ```
2. test case -->  failed

   ```
   let obj = {staff_changes: []};
   for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    obj.staff_changes.push({
     id: i,
     newStaff.push({
      id: 'staff'+i
     });

    });
   }
   console.log(obj);
   ```

In test case 2, I'm trying to push an array with name 'newStaff' even it is not present in obj.

In console obj with 4 items is displaying but 'newStaff' is not pushing to obj.

Comment: Please post your expected output

Comment: What is `newStaff` and where is it?

Comment: in output only 'id' field is adding but 'newstaff' array is not adding

Answer (score 0):

> You should define `newStaff` as an array variable to push data. And also you have missed to define the  `key` name  inside the array object.

try this

```js
let obj = {staff_changes: []};
let newStaff=[];
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
 newStaff.push({id: 'staff' +i});
 obj.staff_changes.push({
  id: i,
  newStaff: newStaff
 });
}
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

`newStaff` variable not found in test case 2, declare `newStaff` inside `for` loop

```
let obj = {staff_changes: []};

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
let newStaff=[];
 obj.staff_changes.push({
  id: i,
  newStaff:newStaff.push({
   id: 'staff'+i
  });

 });
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Better is declare `newStaff` outside the for loop because this way it will be creating new variable every time loop executing

Comment: @Pardeep Jain Exactly you are right, but if we declare newStaff out side the for loop than it should be initialized it inside for loop other wise this variable contain the old value, so that i declare it inside for loop

Comment: Yes, but using your code it will always empty your array so what's the logic of pushing into empty array everytime?

Comment: Yes in this case it will empty every time but suppose if he/she need to push any thing in side for loop in  the next line of code so it will be meaningful in this case i think

Comment: Kindly upvote if you think this answer is helpful Thanks

Comment: Never assume requirements of questionior , anyways your approach may be correct but not suitable as per question

Answer (score 0):

You need this piece of code -

```
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
 obj.staff_changes.push({
  id: i,
  key: {
   id: 'staff'+i
  }

 });
}
```