# why console.log() creating /**id:4**/ and /**ref:4**/ values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, for-loop, console.log

Few mins ago I did  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50622174/2218635)  and the answer snippet is below

```js
let obj = {staff_changes: []};
let newStaff=[];
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
 newStaff.push({id: 'staff' +i});
 obj.staff_changes.push({
  id: i,
  newStaff: newStaff
 });
}
console.log(obj);
```

*If you run this above snippet, you can see `/**id:4**/` and `/**ref:4**/` . What is this?*

When the code on execution time, that was  pushing same duplicate values into a array. So I hope  at the starting time it's generating a `Id:4` and if the same duplicate value will exist, then just it write a comment like `/**ref:4**/`  where `4` means `Id=:4` which is generated already.

> So I want to know  **Is my understand is correct?**. If my understanding is correct , **then how can we avoid this?** Shall I use `object.assign()` before push the value into array to avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data structure contains multiple references to the same object. `console.log` is intelligent enough to abbreviate the output.

Note that (AFAIK), the specification does not guarantee any particular output from `console.log` for objects that aren't instances of `String`, so you cannot rely on that output being the same across browsers, versions, phases of the moon, etc.

Consider an infinitely recursive data structure like `const a = []; a.push(a); console.log(a)`, which one would you prefer: your computer to lock up while printing an infinitely recursive array or `console.log` abbreviating it?

```js
const a = []
a.push(a)
console.log(a)
// [
//   /**id:1**/
//   /**ref:1**/
// ]
```

Comment: So this issue related with console.log() or JavaScript?

Comment: this is not an issue @RameshRajendran just `console.log`s behavior

Comment: What issue? There is no issue. You have created a data structure with multiple references to the same object, which is perfectly allowed and sensible, and `console.log` choses to print it in a certain way, which is perfectly allowed and sensible.

Comment: That's why I asked `object.assign()` to create a new reference for those values.

Comment: Consider an infinitely recursive data structure like `const a = []; a.push(a); console.log(a)`, which one would you prefer: your computer to lock up while printing an infinitely recursive array or `console.log` abbreviating it?

Comment: If you do that, then you have a completely different data structure, which is definitely an "issue" for clients of your data structure who expect it to look a certain way.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your console tools, they will display an object like this in different ways. Those comments are telling you there is more information deeper in the object.

If you want to see the internals in a consistent way, you can stringify the whole object

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

in which case you get:

> {"staff_changes":[{"id":0,"newStaff":[{"id":"staff0"},{"id":"staff1"},{"id":"staff2"},{"id":"staff3"}]},{"id":1,"newStaff":[{"id":"staff0"},{"id":"staff1"},{"id":"staff2"},{"id":"staff3"}]},{"id":2,"newStaff":[{"id":"staff0"},{"id":"staff1"},{"id":"staff2"},{"id":"staff3"}]},{"id":3,"newStaff":[{"id":"staff0"},{"id":"staff1"},{"id":"staff2"},{"id":"staff3"}]}]}

In some developer tools, you can expand the object when you log it to the console, but the above string output shows you the whole lot consistently across tools.